# Strings & Pointers

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I have a question related to strings and pointers.
Please explain only with C/C++ programs....

There is a file, which contains 1 word in each line.
I knew the no. of words that are there in the file. Please explain with the help of small code, how I can store those words in RAM, efficiently.

Is `fscanf(fp,"%s",word) & strcpy` , the only way to store the words in RAM... no other efficient algo or logic available..

Thanks.

Comment: RAM ? Programs are usually concerned with either stack or heap.

Comment: Do you want C or C++? They're two different languages. You tagged C, so I assume you're not really interested in C++ answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the most efficient way to do this is to read the whole file into memory in one block (use `fread`). Then allocate an array of pointers, one for each word. Then walk through the file in memory, changing the `\n` characters to `\0` and storing a pointer the the character after each `\0` in your array.

It is efficient because it only performs one I/O operation, two memory allocations, and loops over the characters in the file twice (once to copy them to the buffer, and once again to break them up into separate strings). The algorithm you describe (`fscanf` and `strcpy`) will perform many I/O operations, allocate memory for each word, and loops over the characters at least three times (once to read into the buffer, once to find the length to allocate memory for, and once to copy from the buffer into the allocated memory).

Here's a simple version with no error checking:

```
char* buffer; // pointer to memory that will store the file
char** words; // pointer to memory that will store the word pointers

// pass in FILE, length of file, and number of words
void readfile(FILE *file, int len, int wordcnt)
{
    // allocate memory for the whole file
    buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
    // read in the file as a single block
    fread(buffer, 1, size, file);

    // allocate memory for the word list
    words = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * wordcnt);
    int found = 1, // flag indicating if we found a word
                   // (starts at 1 because the file begins with a word)
        curword = 0; // index of current word in the word list

    // create a pointer to the beginning of the buffer
    // and advance it until we hit the end of the buffer
    for (char* ptr = buffer; ptr < buffer + len; ptr++)
    {
        // if ptr points to the beginning of a word, add it to our list
        if (found)
            words[curword++] = ptr;
        // see if the current char in the buffer is a newline
        found = *ptr == '\n';
        // if we just found a newline, convert it to a NUL
        if (found)
            *ptr = '\0';
    }
}
```

Here's a slightly simpler version using `strtok`:

```
char* buffer;
char** words;

void readfile(FILE *file, int len, int wordcnt)
{
    buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
    fread(buffer, 1, size, file);
    buffer[len] = '\0';

    words = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * wordcnt);
    int curword = 0;
    char* ptr = strtok(buffer, "\n");
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        words[curword++] = ptr;
        ptr = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    }
}
```

Note that the above two examples assume that the last word in the file ends with a newline!

Comment: keep in mind that reading a file byte by byte or block by block has not much performance difference, since operating system reads block by block anyways. So your approach only puts extra work on programming side with not much gain.

Comment: This is a good solution, but will probably break down inefficiently when a lower-end system has to allocate 256MB of memory or so.

Comment: @AbiusX: The number of I/O calls made could have quite a large impact on the running time of a simple program like this.

Comment: @malfy: If the word list is 256MB, no algorithm will be able to avoid having to allocate 256MB to hold it, and mine stores it with the least overhead possible (without using compression). The only difference is that mine will require the address space to be contiguous, but that's not a bit problem will all modern VM CPUs.

Comment: @AGeek: I commented the first example for you.

Comment: Okk.. i have understood the little bit of it... but my question is will it faster than fscanf("%s"..)/strcpy.... how is your program efficient.....??

Comment: @AGeek: OK, I've added some commentary on its efficiency.

Comment: How can i deallocate the memory that is allocated... This solution sounds good to me... I mean if we have a large file, and have to read that into memory... would this be the efficient solution in all casess????

Comment: @AGeek: To deallocate the memory, just `free(buffer); free (words);`. I can't imagine why this wouldn't be the most efficient method, but you'll have to try it for yourself to see if it is.

Comment: @Gabe... What if we don't know the size of the file.. i.e. you have initialized buffer array of len size.... what if don't know len?? its a random file, and we know the no. of words and the filename.. thats it..

Comment: @AGeek: If you know the filename but not the length, use `stat`. Or `fseek` to the end of the file, get the length with `ftell`, and then `rewind` back to the beginning. The second one is much less efficient, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could read the entire file into a block of memory, then walk through the block, replacing each '\r' or '\n' with a 0. Now you can recover all the strings just by searching through the block for characters immediately following one or more 0's. That's about as space-efficient as you're going to get. Now, if you also want fast access, you could allocate another block of pointers, and set each one to point to the beginning of a string. Still more efficient than a block of pointers each pointing to a separately-allocated String.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your strings not to consume extra not-used bytes, Do this:

```
char * * array=new char*[COUNT_OF_WORDS];


fscanf(fp,"%s",word);
int len=strlen(word);
array[i]=new char[len+1];
strcpy(array[i],word);
```

Comment: What C compiler are you using that supports `new char *[COUNT_OF_WORDS]` ?

Comment: *Please explain only with C/C++ programs*

Comment: @Chris: Probably a C++ compiler!

Answer (score 0):

Why `strcpy`? Just fscanf directly into the target memory.

Comment: The problem is that you don't know how much to allocate for the target memory. The OP is probably thinking `fscanf` into a buffer, figure out the length of the string, allocate enough memory for just that string, and `strcpy` into the newly allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you quoted -- "Please explain only with C/C++ programs...." using a vector that holds string is easy - `std::vector< std::string >`

```
std::string word;

std::vector < std::string > readWords ;  // A vector to hold the read words.

ifstream myfile ("fileToRead.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while ( myfile.good() )
    {
       getline (myfile,word);  // This gets you the first word get copied to line.
       readWords.push_back(word) ; // Each read word is being copied to the vector
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

All read words are copied in the vector `readWords` , you can iterate through it to see what they actually are.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty way to do it, no error checking, using static mem, and using fgets.

```
#define MAX_NUM_WORDS   10
#define MAX_LEN 128

void get_words(char *p_file, char *words)
{
  FILE *f;

  f = fopen(p_file, "r");
  while (fgets(words, MAX_LEN, f))
    words += MAX_LEN+1;

  fclose(f); 
}

main()
{
  char word_array[MAX_NUM_WORDS][MAX_LEN+1];
  int i;

  get_words("words.txt", word_array);

  for (i=0; i<MAX_NUM_WORDS; i++)
    printf("Word: %s", word_array[i]);
}
```

Comment: I assumed the max length of each word is also known.  If it's not known, then we cannot use static mem and have to dynamically allocate memory.